# Is it possible to create visualizations(charts) on our own using tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

The time taken to load the charts(visualization) using tableau in my mobile app is close to 10 or 15 secs. So i am looking for alternative methods like creating my own chart but only to use the intelligence tableau provides on creating the visualizations.

In short, i want to know whether there is some support or API available from tableau using which i can draw the visualizations by myself in my mobile app without losing any chart data or functionality like digging deeper in charts.

For example, an API from tableau using which i can create the chart in my mobile app. After creating it, if user touches any data that should be sent again to tableau to get further event action like showing filters/tables etc.

Is this even possible? I did lot of research in tableau and got to know about tableau SDK, tableau API's, tableau extensions etc. but unable to find what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau provides a thorough white paper [Designing Efficient Workbooks](https://www.tableau.com/learn/whitepapers/designing-efficient-workbooks). I would start by reading that and trying some of the recommendations.

Comment: I will definitely go through that. But like i asked, is there any way Tableau provides support for us to create visualizations on our end(Instead of creating it with tableau desktop and publishing it to tableau server) using some sort of API/data? I am using the site created in iOS mobile application now. Is there any way, i can render the visualization on my own backed by tableau support and show it in app?

Comment: It seems to me you are asking whether Tableau allows you to use some other tool to perform its core function. If that's what you want to do, go ahead and use the other tool of your choice instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an API driven visualization system, you can check out [MuzeJS](http://www.charts.com/muze).

You load your data in an in-browser DataModel, run relational algebra enabled data operators to get the right subset of data, and then just pass to Muze engine, which automatically renders the best visualization for it.

It is similar to the kind of intelligence Tableau provides but since it is a developer first API, you can customize as you want, whether it be for the mobile or the desktop. In fact, most of the charts will be available for both seamlessly.

Any changes to data (including application of data operations) automatically updates the visualization, without you having to do anything else.

Add to that, if you’ve to connect multiple charts (for cross-interactivity, drill-down etc.), you’ve to manually write the ‘glue’ code. With Muze, all charts rendered from the same DataModel are automatically connected (enabling cross-filtering). It also provides composability and the ability to facet your visualization, providing a multi-grid layout.

You can go through some of the [examples](https://www.charts.com/muze/examples) and the [documentation](https://www.charts.com/muze/docs/getting-started) to see if it suits your needs